# Using gpg4win in Cygwin | WARNING: unsafe permissions on homedir

Tags: windows, cygwin, gnupg, yubico, gpg-agent

I finally managed to configure a yubikey 4 on windows using gpg4win and cygwin. I can run the following command in Cygwin and my yubikey prompts for pin and starts blinking then it does its job properly.

```
echo "$(uname -a)" | gpg --encrypt --sign --armor --default-key $KEYID --recipient $KEYID  | gpg --decrypt --armor
```

However, when I want to use it for git signing, it gives me this error:

```
WARNING: unsafe permissions on  homedir c:\users\***\AppData\Roaming\gnupg
```

I have proper signingKey and program settings in my .gitconfig

Any body knows how to change permission on .gnupg folder?

Comment: I had the same issue, my answer was to use gpg4win instead of cygwin. It isn't a fix to your permissions, but it'll get you a command-line gpg.